# Replace strings with new strings

Tags: 7, string-overrides

I have a page with list of teasers. It contain links like 1 comment, 1 new comment, add your comment. I want to change 1 comment to 1 response, 1 new comment to 1 new response and add new comment to add new response. 
I used **[string overrides module](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides)** and tried to change the strings, but i was able to change only add new comment to add new response. How to change 1 comment and 1 new comment? please help.
[image]

Comment: Is your site multilingual already?

Comment: @molot : no, it is not multilingual.

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution to implement `hook_preprocess_node` to modify the comments links.

You can follow the answers in the [Modifying teaser node comment links](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36290/modifying-teaser-node-comment-links)

Answer (score 0):

If you need only few strings redefined, String Overrides is a good solution. If you want to redefine most of them, or if your site is multilingual anyway, there is a better way:

- Be sure that internationalization modules are installed and enabled
- Go to *Administration » Configuration » Regional and language*
- Click *Add language*, and create something like *English GB*
- "Translate" strings you want to have changed

Comment: Thanks Molot, I tried the steps, but under Translate interface I did not found any string like comment or new comment. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Nikhil in my setup, you can find *@count new comments* at /admin/config/regional/translate/edit/2050 - others are there to be found, too. Can't quite guess why you cannot. If my address works for you, I can post all the rest as well.

Comment: I tried to find @count new comments and also tried the link /admin/config/regional/translate/edit/2050 but it is showing nothing.